# How to link a c++ program to jvm (java virtual machine)?

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk, openjdk

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI) tutorial which creates a JVM from a c++ program. The program compiles but when it runs it fails with

```
error while loading shared libraries: libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The program (it is a direct copy from the linked tutorial):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
   JavaVM *jvm;                      // Pointer to the JVM (Java Virtual Machine)
   JNIEnv *env;                      // Pointer to native interface
       //================== prepare loading of Java VM ============================
   JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;                        // Initialization arguments
   JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];   // JVM invocation options
   options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";   // where to find java .class
   vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;             // minimum Java version
   vm_args.nOptions = 1;                          // number of options
   vm_args.options
   = options;
   vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;     // invalid options make the JVM init fail
       //=============== load and initialize Java VM and JNI interface =============
   jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);  // YES !!
   delete options;    // we then no longer need the initialisation options.
   if (rc != JNI_OK) {
          // TO DO: error processing...
         std::cin.get();
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
      //=============== Display JVM version =======================================
   cout << "JVM load succeeded: Version ";
   jint ver = env->GetVersion();
   cout << ((ver>>16)&0x0f) << "."<<(ver&0x0f) << endl;

   // TO DO: add the code that will use JVM <============  (see next steps)

   jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
   cin.get();
}
```

The makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall 
SOURCES= main.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=searchEngineCpp
PROG_PATH = /

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ -L/usr/bin/java -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm

.cpp.o:
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -g -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux

clean:
   rm -rf *.o searchEngineCpp
```

I have tried setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/amd64/server
```

I saw a few posts that recommended making sure the JAVA_HOME variable was pointing; I made sure it pointed to the above folder.

There were also other posts that recommended running `sudo R CMD javareconf`

The JAVA_HOME variable there was `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, however you will need to be sure to use the same path as you gave in the Makefile linker command, i.e.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

(FWIW you don't need `-L/usr/bin/java` in the linker command.)

You can check that the path is correct using `ldd` ex.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server ldd ./searchEngineCpp
```

For a more permanent solution, you could add a file to the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory, and then run `ldconfig` to update the dynamic linker cache. The name is not important so long as it's meaningful to you. For example:

```
echo '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server' | 
  sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/java-8-openjdk-amd64.conf

sudo ldconfig
```